# 'new' runs out of memory with very little memory allocated

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I'm working on a large scientific code to be run non-interactively on a cluster. The code uses a singleton scheme to store large matrices in memory, for repeated future multiplications. Lately the code has been crashing, usually soon after allocation of a certain type of these matrices, with our exception handler returning output like this:

> ## std::bad_alloc caught in TerminateHandler ##########
>
> New ran out of memory.
>   Peak RSS memory    = 905179136 bytes
>   Current RSS memory = 905179136 bytes
>
> #######################################################

Each process ought to have at least 16 GB of RAM available to it, so it is difficult to see how we could already be running out of memory at 905179136 bytes; furthermore, manipulating the code to use more or less memory results in the program still crashing, but with a smaller (larger) value for 'peak RSS memory' reported.

I can think of two possibilities:

1. Memory fragmentation.
2. A very large 'new' request is being made for some reason, such that we would exceed 16 GB if it were serviced.

It may be relevant that this is a CUDA application, and the matrices are being built on the CPU in order to be sent to the GPU and then deleted. The GPU reports no errors, however.

Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce the bug in tests, and running within valgrind or gdb up to the crash is sufficiently slow (i.e. days of wallclock time) that the queue system kills my job. My question is how to distinguish between these possibilities, or what others might there be? In particular is there some way to report the size of all calls to 'new'?

Comment: Overload the `new` operator and add whatever logging functionality you need.

Comment: Yeah, that'd work I suppose

Comment: Also, add code to your new logging functionality @CaptainObvlious mentioned to get a pmap of the process - it's possible something did something like a `mmap()` or `shmat()` with a fixed address that's blocking growth of the heap.

Comment: Is this running as a 64 bit process?

Comment: Running a release build (with symbols) in gdb shouldn't be slow. gdb won't be doing anything, just waiting for the program to break.

Comment: make sure when you submit your job that you specify that the job should be alone on the node.